# How to create Layout Based on Layer in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am trying to create a different layout for a sub-section of my website using Orchard.

Let's say I wanted to give `www.site.com/Shop` a different layout from the rest of the website; how would I go about doing this?

I have tried looking for a way to do this using layers but have got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve different layout, since I don't know your specific needs I'll throw in some extra possible routes

## Use url shape alternate (I guess you need this one)

You have to enable **Url Alternates** module and it lets you create shape alternates based on url. For example if your page is **www.site.com/shop** you can then create view under your theme **Layout-url-Shop.cshtml** and it will be used instead of default **Layout.cshtml** on your shop.

[Orchard documentantion: URL and Widget Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)

## Use 1.x or wait for 1.9

There you can define dynamically different layout per content item aka page. But I find it good only for content not the base layout which is present in layout.cshtml

## Create minisite

[How to create a minisite inside your Orchard website](http://english.orchardproject.hu/blog/how-to-create-a-minisite-inside-your-orchard-website)